# problemas con position fixed

Tags: css

tengo 2 contenedores uno con position `relative`  y `fixed`

os esplico que estoy tratando de darle un `width` de `100%` al contenedor que tiene el position **fixed** pero este se sale del contenedor padre , nececito que ocupe el **100%** de el contenedor padre y que tenga una position **fixed**.

como puedo lograr esto?

esto fue lo que intente....

```css
.padre{

    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1500;
    
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.hijo{

    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;
    background: rgb(240,240,240,0.5);
    z-index: 1500;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">


<div class="hijo">
  bienvenido
</div>

 
</div>
```

Comment: No puedes hacer eso, cuando un elemento tiene `position:fixed` se posiciona respecto a la ventana del navegador. Si quieres que tenga el mismo ancho que el padre tendrás que ponerle una medida fija.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que el hijo se quede siempre a los pies del padre, lo puedes conseguir con `position:absolute;`en lugar de `fixed`. Por favor lea el comentario de @blonfu.

Observación: los `z-index` tan grandes no tienen sentido.

```css
.padre{

    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1500;/*Que barbaridad!!*/
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.hijo{

    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;
    background: rgb(240,240,240,0.5);
    z-index: 1500;/*Que barbaridad!!*/
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">


<div class="hijo">
  bienvenido
</div>

 
</div>
```